# Wrapping text around an image or linking two TextBlocks in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, word-wrap

I am creating a program that shows text and an image in the same window. The Image is in the top-left corner of the screen and the Text will begin to the right of it, and then continue down below the image.

Currently, what I am trying is to take two TextBlocks (one to the right of the image and one below both the image and the first textblock) and want to have the text continue from one block to the other. Is this an ideal approach, and if so, how would I do it? Is there a better/easier way than this or can I do it with just one object? Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I believe FlowDocuments can be used for this, but I can't give a direct answer.  Please see the ref here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx.  You almost certainly want to create a document with the image and the text, as in a word processor document.  Not possible with two TextBlocks.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 24):

I would not recommend using TextBlocks to achieve this type of layout. As Kieren suggests, a FlowDocument would be ideal for this type of a design. Take a look at this XAML snippet and the resulting WPF app screenshot using a FlowDocument with a Paragraph element and a Floater element containing an image:

```
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>                
            <Paragraph>
                <Floater Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,5,5" Padding="3">
                    <BlockUIContainer>
                        <Image Source="/FlowDocumentTest;component/dog.png" Width="100" /> 
                    </BlockUIContainer>
                </Floater>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Suspendisse et diam felis. Vestibulum ac nisl mi. 
                Etiam varius velit lobortis nibh vestibulum nec consequat velit pellentesque. 
                Cras commodo libero placerat nulla dapibus eget porttitor ligula tempor. 
                Donec nisl massa, congue et pretium sit amet, feugiat vel est. 
                Nulla dapibus metus in justo pulvinar sit amet viverra lorem rhoncus. 
                Integer placerat interdum massa et mattis.</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: How to create this thing via C#?

Comment: FlowDocuments have limited support for data binding which can be problematic with dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind try this:

```
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = GetUri("Images/ScanHead.png", typeof(PrintService));
            bi.EndInit();
            image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            image.Source = bi;

            InlineUIContainer b = new InlineUIContainer(image);
            b.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center;
            p.Inlines.Add(b);
            InlineUIContainer b2 = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() { Text="Text\r\n2nd row"});
            p.Inlines.Add(b2);

            p.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontSize = 18;
            fd.Blocks.Add(p);
```