# How to "float" image in XAML (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to do in XAML something like ffloat:left for an image in CSS. I need to create something like this:

[image]

with variable image dimensions and text length.

**Edit**: The text warp around the image is not static in my case, it is create in C# code that returns a list of TextBlock elements (with Runs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems to be using  RichTextBlockOverflow and  OverflowContentTarget described in this presentation: http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/APP-914T_Street.pptx

Comment: Spot on! Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblockoverflow(v=win.10).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

With Silverlight 4 you would achieve this using a `RichTextBox`:

```
 <RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"  IsReadOnly="False">  
   <Paragraph>  
        More text here .. 
        <InlineUIContainer>  
            <Image Source="abc.jpg"/>  
        </InlineUIContainer>   
        more and more text here;  
        <LineBreak />  
    </Paragraph>  
</RichTextBox>
```

It looks like Win8 Metro has a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.aspx), and also has an [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx), so something like the above should work!

Comment: how do you create this in C#? I have a list of TextBlocks (with Runs) so I guess I could convert the firts one to this and I would be ok

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339051/wrapping-text-around-an-image-or-linking-two-textblocks-in-c-sharp-wpf) seems to be asking for something similar to what you want. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340956/921321) should prove a solution to what you desire.

A summary of the answer is, use a `FlowDocument` like the following example:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Image Source="/FlowDocumentTest;component/dog.png" Width="100" /> 
            </BlockUIContainer>
        </Floater>
        Here is where the text goes to wrap around the image.
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

**Update**

As your question states, you are now using some C# code to generate TextBlock/Run Elements, both can be children of a Paragraph object. So simply name your `Paragraph` like so:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph x:Name="textPara">
        <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Image Source="/FlowDocumentTest;component/dog.png" Width="100" /> 
            </BlockUIContainer>
        </Floater>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Then in C#, add your generated `TextBlock`s or `Run`s to the `Inlines` property of textPara, i.e.

```
var runToInsert = new Run("Some text to display");
textPara.Inlines.InsertAfter(textPara.Inlines.FirstInline, runToInsert);
```

Comment: I edited the question. The Text on is not static in my case but a bunch of textboxes. I insert them into a StackPanel but how do I insert them to this?

Comment: Updated my answer with how you can dynamically add content.

Comment: I do not think that Paragprah in a Paragraph is valid. The compiler agress

Comment: @IgorKulman My mistake, I misread the MSDN documentation, will update with a better example

Comment: btw, the FlowDocument must be placed in a FlowDocumentPageViewer that creates UI elements like paging that are no wanted in my scenario

Comment: I've updated my answer, and use a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, disable the scrollbars and any other features if desired :)

Comment: thanks for trying ;) but the updated code does not work for me (copied as is), the text always shown under the image

Comment: Have you inspected the visual tree using a tool like snoop? The answer I linked seemed to work, so maybe try giving the `Floater` a width and see if that makes any difference, if not, I'm not really sure.

Comment: setting width helps but I cannot foind out how to disable all the unseired function of FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Comment: bad news, I was trying the code in WPF but in Windows 8 Metro there is no FlowDocument

Comment: Ah, it looks like it hasn't been added into the current build yet. I think it will be eventually though, until then I have no idea.