# Wrap text around the image in TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to wrap text around the image in TextBlock?

The text is always at the bottom...

Which are the basic approach in general to do it?

[image]

Thank you!

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"http://cl.jroo.me/z3/P/0/C/d/a.aaa-bad-crazy-cat.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
image.EndInit();

var imageInline = new InlineUIContainer { Child = new Image { Source = image  } };

textBlock1.Inlines.Add(imageInline);

textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run{ Text = "any text goes here..."});
```

Comment: Is the Text at the bottom or wrapped? Seems conflicting.

Comment: You can use a Floater in a FlowDocument - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339051/wrapping-text-around-an-image-or-linking-two-textblocks-in-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well... Text looks like at the bottom and yes it is wrapped as well.

Comment: @Jogy  Yeah.. I found it as well... But 2 things are: I need auto resizible control and don't need control panel of FlowDocumentViewer at all.

Comment: +1 for using the wikipedia definition of Lorem Ipsum as filler text, gave me a good laugh

Comment: @KDiTraglia hahahahah :) yep!

Comment: @Peretz You can use FlowDocumentScrollViewer - it will display just the content and a scrollbar if needed, without any other controls.

Comment: If a FlowDocumentScrollViewer is OK then maybe remove the TextBlock from the title.   A RichTextBox will also display a FlowDocument

Comment: @Blam Yeah.. But is RichTextBox is too "heavy"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put them into two different columns in a grid...